# Node.js Loopback : TypeError: Cannot read property 'createModel' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, loopbackjs

Super Noob here, I have a problem with a REST API using loopback here is my error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createModel' of undefined
at module.exports (/home/...../node_modules/loopback-component-oauth2/lib/models/oauth2-models.js:35:30)
at module.exports (/home/...../node_modules/loopback-component-oauth2/lib/models/index.js:24:42)
at Function.module.exports [as oAuth2Provider] (/home/...../node_modules/loopback-component-oauth2/lib/oauth2-loopback.js:48:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/...../server/server.js:17:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

here is what I have in my server.js :

```
'use strict';

var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');
// pour OATH2
var oauth2 = require('loopback-component-oauth2');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

// OATH2
var options = {
    dataSource: app.dataSources.db, // Data source for oAuth2 metadata persistence
    loginPage: '/login', // The login page URL
    loginPath: '/login' // The login form processing URL
};

oauth2.oAuth2Provider(
    app, // The app instance
    options // The options
);

app.start = function() {
    // start the web server
    return app.listen(function() {
        app.emit('started');
        var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
        console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
        if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
            var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
            console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
        }
    });
};

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // start the server if `$ node server.js`
    if (require.main === module)
        app.start();
});
```

I've checked a whole lot of similar topics and haven't been able to figure out any solutions for my problem.
I've noticed that my database was "{}" when I did a console log, that it put a different error if i put all my OATH2 in the app start function, but it looks like it's not the way to go.

Thanks a lot for your help (and please forgive me if it's not clear enough :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move these set of code to below app.start(), because when you declare an options, app haven't initialize yet, so undefined object was assigned at that stage.

```
// OATH2
var options = {
     dataSource: app.dataSources.db, // Data source for oAuth2 metadata persistence
     loginPage: '/login', // The login page URL
     loginPath: '/login' // The login form processing URL
};

oauth2.oAuth2Provider(
     app, // The app instance
     options // The options
 );
```